# What is required in Delphi 2007 to use Variant arrays?

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2007, variant

I'm a newbie in Delphi, using Delphi 2007.  I am learning things related to COM programming, in order to make a basic plugin to a program called Retail Pro. I have a little of background in .NET (C#, ASP), NetBeans (Java, JSF) and PHP.

Anyway, I'm following this intro tutorial to COM Programming :

[An Introduction to COM Programming with Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/comoleactivex/a/comdelphi.htm)

At second and third parts of the [5th lesson](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa122104a.htm) about Variant Arrays,  there are sample codes to download.  Here is the sample code of second part:

http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/code/src122104_sample.zip

When I compile the code, it gives me a lot of errors of undeclared identifier (`VarType`, `VarArrayCreate`, `VarArrayLowBound`, etc).  Is there some class to add in the `uses` section in order to be able to compile this piece of code?

Comment: Marco, what happens when you put your cursor on the VarArrayCreate identifier and stike "F1" key ?

Comment: Exactly that, it brings me to variant documentation, i'm feel a little foreign with delphi, yet

Comment: In that documentation somewhere near the top it documents it belongs to "variants" unit

Comment: perhaps the articles (and the source code files) were written in 1999/2000 for Delphi v.5 :-D

Comment: The tutorials at http://www.techvanguards.com are very useful for learning how to write COM-based plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is missing a unit from the `uses` clause. That unit is named `Variants` and contains all the symbols that the compiler cannot find. Add that unit and the code will compile.

Comment: ...se agradece la respuesta